# Decompile raw binary code to assembly

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have binary code that I'll like to disassemble to assembly. This code is not part of structured exe or dll file so `objdump` and `gdb` do not recognize it.

How can I disassemble it to assembly?

Comment: Do you know the format of this code e.g. it's binary for which platform/architecture etc?

Comment: yes, this is Windows code. This code is copy to memory allocated by `VirtualAlloc` and then run with `CreateThread` Win32 API call

Comment: So my idea would be to add apropriate win exe headers etc to make it [PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) and then even if not it's not 100% PE try to disassemby it using e.g. [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_disassembler.htm), but I haven't tested that before.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to be possible with PE Explorer

Comment: I don't know what your normal coding platform is, but if I were in your situation I would probably just create a dummy asm routine with just a single db statement and put the binary code there. I would then use the debugger to step into that and have the IDE show me what it represents. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB and `objdump` rely on section information in System V ELF binaries in order to disassemble them. In other words, in order for `gdb` and `objdump` to work, the code to be analyzed must be in an ELF binary and that binary must have an intact section header table that accurately describes the layout of the binary.

> How can I decompile it to assembly?

Decompilation is the reconstruction of source code from a binary. Disassembly is translation of CPU instructions into assembly language.

> I have binary code that I'll like to disassemble to assembly.

If you have machine code to disassemble and the instruction set architecture of the code is known, one tool that may help is the [Capstone disassembly framework](http://www.capstone-engine.org/). Here is a demo using python bindings: [Python tutorial for Capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html).

[Radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) is another option.

If this is not helpful, there is a [reverse engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)  site on StackExchange where you are more likely to find exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can try radare2. first, read documents. if you have question connect to the community. it's very resoncive.

you get infomation your binary with r2:

`r2 -A ./Binary
r2>>> iI ## for binary information`